# unable to understand parsing of concatenated string PHP

Tags: php

I have the below code :

```
$a="A";

$arr=array("a"=>"A","b"=>"B","c"=>"C");

function test($v){
    global $arr;
    echo "$v,";
    return $arr[$v];
}

echo $a.test('b').test('c');
```

I expected the answer `Ab,Bc,C` but its output `b,c,ABC`.

i checked it from right to left and left to right. But in both cases the output is different than my assumption.

**EDIT :**
Look here the difference

```
echo $a.test('b').test('c'); //Output b,c,ABC
echo "<br/>";
echo $a,test('b'),test('c'); //Output Ab,Bc,C
```

Comment: Can you describe more

Comment: To get expected result:   return "$v,".$arr[$v]; So, don't echo before return:https://eval.in/920237

Comment: echo $a.test('b').test('c'); echo $a,test('b'),test('c');  both give different result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This due to `instruction completion`. Code execute after termination with symbol `;` semicolon, in this example

```
echo $a.",".test('b').",".test('c');
```

You are calling `test('b')` in which function execute first run this line `echo "$v,";` because its terminate first before line `echo $a.",".test('b').",".test('c');` and after `echo "$v,";` it returns `$arr[$v]`  value `B` and `C`.

After calling function it runs this line  `echo $a.",".test('b').",".test('c');` which is `A,B,C`;

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. But i have made some edit to my question to describe my problem more